# Visualizing a multilayered perceoptron for image classification

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

As part of a project I'm working on, I have built a "fully connected layer" (multilayered perceptron) network for image classification. Even though I know how to build an convolutional NN, for various reasons I had to use a fully connected one.

My question is: given the network, learned to classify with test accuracy of 86%, how can I visualize what each hidden neuron is looking for? And, more broadly, how can I understand better how the network decides how to classify? I have seen many ways to discover this in CNN, but not in fully connected networks.

I used tensorflow to build the network.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with the fully connected networks is that except the output layer, individual units in the hidden layers don't have necessarily any semantic meaning themselves; it is rather the space they induce that is interesting. In other words, in the hidden layers, the network can represent useful things as a combination of activations of many units, without the individual units having a useful meaning without the rest.

However, there are some things you can do still (from :

- You can try finding an image in your dataset that [maximizes the activation of the inspected neuron](http://cs231n.github.io/understanding-cnn/#retrieving-images-that-maximally-activate-a-neuron).
- Use [moving occlusion](http://cs231n.github.io/understanding-cnn/#occluding-parts-of-the-image) to find the part of the image that affects the activation the most.

Moreover, on this site, there is a nice [live demo of activations of a simple FCN](http://scs.ryerson.ca/~aharley/vis/fc/).